# How to add comments to table or column in mysql using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to add comments to the table and columns created of a model.
I tried the `doc` parameter of the `Column` class, like the following:

```
class Notice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tb_notice"
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'MyISAM'}

    seqno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, doc="seqno")
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, doc="notice title")
    detail = db.Column(db.TEXT, nullable=True, doc="notice detail ")
```

But it didn't work, the comments weren't added to the SQL creation statement, and I wonder how to add a comment to the table.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.doc) of `doc` parameter:

> doc¶ – optional String that can be used by the ORM or similar to document attributes on the Python side. This attribute does not render SQL comments; use the Column.comment parameter for this purpose.

And the `comment` parameter:

> comment¶ – Optional string that will render an SQL comment on table creation.

Please note that the `comment` is added in version 1.2 of `SQlAlchemy`

And for adding a comment for the table, you just pass additional `comment` attribute (according to the `Table` class [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.comment)) to your `__table_args__` dictionary. Which is also added in version 1.2

The code would be something like this:

```py
class Notice(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = "tb_notice"
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'MyISAM',
        'comment': 'Notice table'
    }

    seqno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, doc="seqno",
                      comment='Integer representing the sequence number')
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, doc="notice title",
                      comment='Title of the notice, represented as a string')
    detail = db.Column(db.TEXT, nullable=True, doc="notice detail",
                       comment='Notice detail description')
```

The `doc` attribute acts as a docstring of your class:

```py
print(Notice.title.__doc__)
```

will outputs:
`notice title`

Now the corresponding `SQL` table creation statement would be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tb_notice` (
  `seqno` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Integer representing the sequence number',
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title of the notice, represented as a string',
  `detail` text COMMENT 'Notice detail description'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COMMENT='Notice table';
```

You can see that comments were added correctly to both the table and the columns.

Answer (score 8):

comment only supported in version 1.2
New in version 1.2:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.comment

Comment: Links are great, but answers should preferrably be self contained, so an example such as the one written by @rho would improve this quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

in new 1.2 version you can do

```py
class Notice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tb_notice"
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'MyISAM'
        'comment': 'yeah comment'
    }
```