# How is SQLAlchemy's column documentation (Column.doc) actually used?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When creating a `Column` object with SQLAlchemy, you can specify a [documentation string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.doc). Once set, how can this documentation be accessed in Python?

In addition, is using `doc` a good practise for documenting SQL Columns, or would it be better to use [`comment`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.comment) or perhaps [Sphinx's standard for documenting general instance variables](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc parameter creates [python docstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring) for classes and fields of your ORM (see also the [PEP 257](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/)). You can access them through the `__doc__` attribute or through the built-in `help()` function. Probably some IDEs will use them for hints as well.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648353/1635525) for some examples.